# Logistic generalized Additive Model (GAM)

Tags: logistic, classification, algorithms, generalized-additive-model

How are the smoothers fitted in case of Logistic GAMS? For Gaussian response variable, many smoothers are defined such as splines and local regression etc. But how are they used in case of Logistic GAMs? Is the categorical response variable first transformed in continuous variable and then used the smoothers defined for continuous response GAMs?